# mysql add condition for derived max function column

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have the following sql which is not working on the where condition.

```
SELECT t.PROJID,sum(t.UNITS) AS totalunits, sum(t.COST) AS totalcost, project, max(t.DATE) as lastupdated, PROJCODE 
FROM `projectcosts` `t` 
left join projects on projects.PROJID = t.PROJID 
where lastupdated LIKE '%2014-06-11%' 
GROUP BY t.PROJID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `like` on dates.  The right solution is to simply truncate the date and do the comparison.  However, you need to use the field in the data:

```
SELECT t.PROJID, sum(t.UNITS) AS totalunits,
       sum(t.COST) AS totalcost, project, max(t.DATE) as lastupdated, PROJCODE 
FROM `projectcosts` `t` left join
     projects on projects.PROJID = t.PROJID 
where date(t.date) = date('2014-06-11')
GROUP BY t.PROJID;
```

Or, if you have an index on `lastupdated`, using a range allows the use of the index:

```
SELECT t.PROJID, sum(t.UNITS) AS totalunits,
       sum(t.COST) AS totalcost, project, max(t.DATE) as lastupdated, PROJCODE 
FROM `projectcosts` `t` left join
     projects on projects.PROJID = t.PROJID 
where t.date >= date('2014-06-11') and t.date < date('2014-06-12')
GROUP BY t.PROJID;
```

You might really be wanting to use `having`, which is suggested by the use of the column alias instead of the base column.  In that case:

```
SELECT t.PROJID, sum(t.UNITS) AS totalunits,
       sum(t.COST) AS totalcost, project, max(t.DATE) as lastupdated, PROJCODE 
FROM `projectcosts` `t` left join
     projects on projects.PROJID = t.PROJID 
GROUP BY t.PROJID
HAVING date(lastupdated) = date('2014-06-11');
```

Comment: where did you get that value date from?

Answer (score 0):

Like can never be used with date field.
If you are changing the type to vachar it is possible

Comment: Why can't LIKE be used with a date field?

Comment: You can use between , > , < etc. Like can never be recomended.

Comment: 'never be recommended' is very different from 'can never', isn't it? "LIKE '2014-06%'" for instance is fine, perhaps not as fast as "BETWEEN x AND y", but it will use an index if one is available!